# How to I make a my discord bot join a voice channel *in a category*?

Tags: python, discord.py

I'd like to write a bot with the ability to join; This is my code

```py
import json
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

JSON_FILE = r"C:\JSON PATH"
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "~")

with open(JSON_FILE, "r") as json_file:
    TOKEN = json.load(json_file)["token"]
    GUILD = json.load(json_file)["guild"]

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "~")

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f"{bot.user.name} launched and has arrived for further use")

@bot.command(name = "join")
async def join(ctx, voice_channel: commands.VoiceChannelConverter):
    await voice_channel.connect()
    await ctx.send(f"I have joined: {voice_channel}")

@bot.command(name = "leave")
async def leave(ctx):
    server = ctx.message.server
    voice_client = bot.voice_client_int(server)
    await voice_client.disconnect()

bot.run(TOKEN)
```

It can join usual channels but it cannot join channels in categories. Any advice on how to do that?
Thank you in advance

Comment: Are you sure your bot has the permission to join the channel?

Comment: Yes. It does not want to work on servers its admin in

Comment: I just tested it, and it works for me, while the leave command doesn't quite work. Are you maybe using an outdated version of discord.py?

Comment: Should the bot join the author of the command?

Comment: The bot joins the Voice channel which is mentioned, which is only doable by writing <#id_of_voice_channel_here>

Comment: Yes, how do I code that? And how do I fetch the ID automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is probably, that you are using an outdated version of `discord.py` since you are using `server`, which is deprecated since v1.0, and not `guild`. If you update it, it will probably work, because it worked for me too when I tried it.

To code it to automatically join the voice channel of the user executing the command, just use `ctx.author.voice.channel`:

```py
@bot.command(name = "join")
async def join(ctx, voice_channel: commands.VoiceChannelConverter):
    if not ctx.author.voice is None:
        await ctx.author.voice.channel.connect()
        await ctx.send(f"I have joined your voice channel.")
    else:
        await ctx.send("You are not in a voice channel!")
```

---

References:

- [discord.Member.voice](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Member.voice)
- [`Server` is deprecated](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/migrating.html#server-is-now-guild)